# How to save only the rows containing redundant content using awk?

Tags: awk

I know how to remove the rows containing redundant info in one particular column but not how to save ONLY the redundant

For example:

I have the following text (kk.txt) with 3 columns:

```
A 3 qs   
A 8 qs  
A 6 st  
B 3 qs  
A 5 qs  
C 9 st  
D 2 st  
C 3 st
```

If I apply,

```
awk '{if(! a[$1]){print; a[$1]++}}' kk.txt > kk2.txt
```

It gives me:

```
A 3 qs  
B 3 qs  
C 9 st  
D 2 st
```

Instead, I want the opposite:

```
A 3 qs  
A 8 qs  
A 6 st  
A 5 qs  
C 9 st  
C 3 st
```

Any ideas???

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want delete lines those have unique first column (as reference because there is no this `D 2 st` line in your output else `sort -u -k2,3 infile` is what you need), then you can do as following and process the input file twice to print those lines where column#1 repeated more than one time:

```bsh
awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$1]++; next} seen[$1]>1' infile infile
A 3 qs
A 8 qs
A 6 st
A 5 qs
C 9 st
C 3 st
```

Comment: [same as here...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388338/22142)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not looking my old answers most of the times and even I forgot them :   )